# Popular Blackberry web app

Tags: web-applications, blackberry

Do you know any popular Blackberry web app out there.
I've searched in Google but haven't found any (just feel strange).

Comment: This is not programming related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook, Flickr, Twitter... anything with a mobile site that works on a Blackberry?